# Sharing php Session ($_SESSION) across multiple domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, symfony1

I have 2 different domain, let's call them www.foo.com and bar.foo.com. The first one is built with CI, and the second one is built with Symfony. I want to share my session, so if I login in one of them, I can access the other one. I set my session data with `$_SESSION["session_name"] = "value";`.

How to make a session data readable from the other domain?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your original question and your answers to Logan and myself in the comments of the original question I understand:

1 - you want to pass the session variables among a domain and its subdomains; and

2 - CI and Symfony load the session before you have a chance to do the ini_set command.

I believe you have two options:

1 - include the php configuration command in the php.ini file

```
session.cookie_domain=".foo.com"
```

If you try including it in the .htaccess it will not work if you are running php as a CGI module, which seems to be fairly common among shared hosting services.

2 - you can prepend a file to all php scripts in your site. Those will be put on top of every single php script your site runs, even the ones inside CI and Symfony. For example:

phpprepend.php file

```
<?php
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.foo.com');
?>
```

include the following line in your php.ini file:

```
auto_prepend_file = "/path/to/file/phpprepend.php"
```

Please let us know if this solves the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Really thanks to both of you..
I prefer the first option. 
What I've done :
1. Edit the php.ini
2. restart the Apache
3. set the session_name for CI and Symfony
but, it still not working..
are there anything that I missed?

Comment: I tried again the first option, and now, they have a same session name and cookie domain. but, the session from the first domain is not readable from the second one. :(
I'm really appreciate your help.. Thank you very much..

Comment: It's working.. 
thanks guys..
sorry, my bad..
after searching for a long time, finally I found that CI config file call the session_start() exactly after loading that file. so, I replace it after some configuration, like setting session_name, cookie_domain, and soon. Than I added a line to check if the session_id() is not empty to call session_start()..
Thanks very much ...
I really Appreciate your help.. :)

Comment: @Bobby - glad it is working for you. I had a similar problem with joomla. I did not want to hack into the joomla core or the template, so I used the prepend solution I shared in my answer. It simply add the prepend.php file at the top of every single php script loaded. Anyway, congrats on resolving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `session_name` function let they have same session name. This will work for sub domains.
And if they are complete different domains, and if you are using the cookie to pass session id, this will not work because cookie only work for one domain.

Comment: But if the two sites are at different hosts, this won't work. So the OP has to provide some more details.

Comment: Based on the example he gave, it seems he is talking about subdomain and domain (www.foo.com and bar.foo.com). This should work.

Comment: @Bobby check whether they use the same way of dealing session. If framework have set their own session handler, you can not share the session.

Comment: thanks xdazz.. I've miss the session handler.. but, I don't know how to make symfony use the same session name with autoload configuration..

Comment: @Bobby If you are using symfony1.4, the session name setting should be in factories.yml, find the `storage` config section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the session cookie's domain so that it is accessible from both sites.

```
<?php
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.foo.com');
```

Either add that to both sites's PHP code very early on in loading, or add something like this to your .htaccess file in both sites.

```
php_value session.cookie_domain ".foo.com"
```

I'm not 100% sure the second options works, but I think it should.

Comment: @Logan - This parameter is defined as PHP_INI_ALL so you should be able to configure it in the .htaccess or php.ini (http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php). Having said that I don't think you can configure in .htaccess if you are running PHP as a cgi module, which seems to be the most common configuration for shared servers.

Comment: @Bobby You never specified, but I'm assuming these are running on the same server? Where did you add that PHP code? It needs to be added before session_start() called, so maybe just try adding it at the top of index.php to test? What type of hosting do you have?

Comment: @jdias : can you explain it again more specific? And what should I do? sorry, I'm a newbie.. Thx

Comment: @logan : like I said, I used CodeIgniter and Symfony, so, both of them have a configuration to load session_start() automatically.
I tried to add the line that you give me before in my home controller. About the hosting, I use my localhost. I make 2 virtual host. Thanks Logan..

Comment: @Bobby - see my answer below. I could not summarize it here in this comment box due to space and format limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are associated with actual files in the server which contains the session data. So unless the sites have a way of sharing these temporary session files, then they can't share sessions. That is unless the session is serialized and sent the other site. I think the only solution is to implement a session that gets and stores the session data in an external database that the two sites have access to. Then if `server 1` sends the session ID to `server 2` and `server 2` uses it to access the database, it can access the session data stored by `server 1`

Answer (score 0):

Code igniter has the option of using it's [session library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) which has support for storing your sessions is a database, there may be some form of plugin, or you could build your own, for symphony which can read the code igniter sessions out of the database and setup the session inside symphony.

So although they will technically be two different sessions, the database will synchronize them.

This of course assumes that your two sites use the same database.