# PHP Session Variable from subdomain to main domain

Tags: php, session

i Have setup 2 domains/sites in the ISPConfig on amazon Web server EC2 instance,

i have a domain named [app.example.com](http://www.app.example.com) and the other is https://www.example.com
Both domains setup in ISpConfig3. so both have separate webroot and code files.
I have setup some session variables on app.example.com , while on https://www.example.com i have only static contents. But in some cases i need to access the session variables from app.example.com to my top domain https://www.example.com

I have tried setting on http://app.example.com

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );

session_start();

$_SESSION['user_name']= "my_session";
```

and then accessing `$_SESSION['user_name']` on https://www.example.com

```
print_r($_SESSION['user_name']);
```

But nothing seems to be working, How can  i make this to be working?.

Comment: I think this post can answer your question:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328225/sharing-php-session-session-across-multiple-domain][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328225/sharing-php-session-session-across-multiple-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first comment of @Alan Gularte replies quite well I think. If it does not work, you may consider writing a cookie yourself to pass info back and forth.

```
setcookie ("PassMySessionName", $_SESSION['user_name'], time() - 3600, "/", "example.com");
```

Setting cookie domain to "example.com" will make it available both on www. and app.

On the other side you will find it in the $_COOKIE array.

```
$PassedUserName=$_COOKIE["PassMySessionName"];
```

If you need it all to work without cookies enabled, it gets much more complicated, as $_SESSION will work appending parameters to your urls transparently. In that case (if you link from one site to the other) you may add them manually to the urls.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to make a little correction,

Bad: `setcookie ("PassMySessionName", $_SESSION['user_name'], time() - 3600, "/", "example.com");`

Correct: `setcookie ("PassMySessionName", $_SESSION['user_name'], time() + 3600, "/", "example.com");`

Comment: This should be a comment on the answer you're correcting. As an answer, we don't see what you're referring to. (And don't worry, being too old is not a problem). If possible, try to elaborate on why you're correction is better.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, I'm new here; I will redo it ASAP, now I can't because i have less than 50 reputation to comment.