# php session expired on root domain

Tags: php, session, subdomain

I have Created Session on subdomain but right now i am unable to access session variable on Root domain

Login Page : `myaccount.javaignite.com` //authenticate login

Home: page 
`www.javaignite.com` // here i am unable to get the value

**myaccount.javaignite.com/Auth.php**

Calling by ajax from index.php

```
<?php 
$sess_name = session_name('app');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.javaignite.com');
session_start();


if($_POST){


    $profile_id         =$_POST["profile_id"];
    $profile_fullname   =$_POST["profile_fullname"];
    $profile_img        =$_POST["profile_img"];
    $profile_email      =$_POST["profile_email"];


    $_SESSION["profile_id"]         =$profile_id;
    $_SESSION["profile_fullname"]   =$profile_fullname;
    $_SESSION["profile_img"]        =$profile_img;
    $_SESSION["profile_email"]      =$profile_email;


    $redirect_url   ="http://javaignite.com";
    if(isset($_SESSION["redir_url"])){

        $redirect_url   =$_SESSION["redir_url"];

    }
    echo $redirect_url;
    die;



}

?>
```

**javaignite.com/navigation.php**

which is include in myaccount.javaignite.com/index.php and index.php (in root)

```
<?php 
            print_r($_SESSION);

            if(isset($_SESSION["profile_id"])){
                ?>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right:10px;">
                    <li class="dropdown selected"> 
                        <a  class="" href="http://account.javaignite.com/profile"> <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> 
                            <?php echo $_SESSION["profile_name"]; ?> </a> 
                    </li>
                </ul>   


                <?php 

            } else {
            ?>  
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right:10px;">
                    <li class="dropdown selected"> 
                        <a  class="" href="http://account.javaignite.com/"> <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login/Signup </a> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <?php   
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update php.ini file. Please read following older question links
[1.Allow php sessions to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains)

[2.Session variable from subdomain to main domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762527/php-session-variable-from-subdomain-to-main-domain)