# Jquery cross domain login with PHP sessions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have two websites

- www.example.com
- www.m.example.com

The all PHP scripts are based on the first domain. I need to login user from the mobile site using the first domain PHP scripts. And I need to make sessions over the domains. How can I do this?

PHP file:

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

//DB check

$_SESSION['log'] = $dbarray;
?>
```

The script on the second domain

```
$.post('../scripts/login.php',{username:username,password:password},function(data){
  //Success
});
```

Comment: Instead of session use cookies to take that values anywhere on the domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the two domain running on the same server and Apache+PHP stack?
In that case, you just need to set the cookies for `.example.com` instead of `www.example.com` (the default). The session data is stored on the same server, so the session can be shared.

```
<?php
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com');

session_start();
...
```

You can take a look at this answer [Sharing php Session ($_SESSION) across multiple domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328225/sharing-php-session-session-across-multiple-domain)

For JS side, since cross-domain ajax is not allowed. I suggest using a `<form>`element, specify a `redirect` parameter, so that your login script (login.php) can redirect the user back to the right place after login. (you also need to add code in login.php to handle the redirect)

```
<form id="loginForm" action="http://www.example.com/script/login.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="username" value="..."/>
 <input type="hidden" name="password" value="..."/>
 <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.m.example.com/" />
</form>

<script>$("#loginForm").submit();</script>
```

Comment: The two domains are running on a same server

Comment: How can I call external login.php file from jquery?

Comment: changed the answer, see if that helps :)

Comment: But i need to login user from jquery giving errors without page reload

Comment: you probably need more advanced techniques like JSONP. or post the above form to a hidden iframe (but still you can't pass data back from the iframe of different domain)

Comment: I'll try the advance method.. Thanks so much! :)