# Sharing PHP files and session across multiple domains (or subdomains) on the same server

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have multiple sites on a server (multiple domains and subdomains) that share the same php files. This is not a problem for php files that are normally included, but for outward web facing files, calling php files on a different domain will lose the session.

I don't want to share sessions between the sites. If I am on both sites, the session functionality (e.g. login) must remain separate.

So, for example, if I am on DOMAIN1 and I want to call bar.php on DOMAIN2, I want to keep my current DOMAIN1 session.

One solution I have seen posted is to pass the session_name around with every page and then set the session name. Something like (untested):

```
session_name($session_name);
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain1.com');
session_start();
```

I came up with another solution. I created a php file called shell.php on DOMAIN1. In it I include the php file on DOMAIN2

Note: this is just pseudocode for readability - I did not properly escape the url slashes. I will also have to validate that the file is on my domain.

```
<a href="<?php echo "http://domain1/shell.php?file=root/path/to/bar.php&myvar=foo ?>">
```

In shell.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
    $file = $_GET['file'];
    if (file_exists($file)){
        include($file);
    }
}
```

This solution works.
It keeps the user on DOMAIN1: and the session issue is handled. Plus the url in the browser is for the correct site and any passed $_POST or $_GET is available to the included file.

I have seen quite a few posts asking for solutions to sharing sessions across domains and subdomains but have not seen this solution anywhere.  I am wondering about any downsides I may have missed - whether from a performance or security standpoint.

Comment: You've got a major security hole (unless that's all psuedocode). I.e. http://domain1/shell.php?file=http://drevil.com/eviltools.php could make your server run anything I want it to.

Comment: it's still very vulnerable though - you'd have to avoid using $_GET entirely. Answering the question depends a bit too much on what you're actually intending on sharing between the domains.

Comment: @LukeBriggs Yes, I will have to insure that only files that on my site are allowed to be included. After encrypting / decrypting the link, I will have to verify the path of the link is local to my domain. In terms of what is shared between domains, it can be any php code or resource (e.g. image) except the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing php Session ($\_SESSION) across multiple domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328225/sharing-php-session-session-across-multiple-domain)