# Cookie Logging [PHP]

Tags: php, cookies, fwrite

The text file is created, nothing is being stored.

```
<?php
$cookie = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
$file = fopen('cookie.txt', 'a');
fwrite($file, $cookie . "\n\n");
?>
```

What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

A few problems.

1) Session ID assumes you have a session running.  I don't see a `session_start();` so I would assume the cookie never gets set.

2) `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` is very unreliable.  Use `session_id()` instead combined with `session_start()`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by setting the session.

Comment: You are accessing a variable called PHPSESSID which is short form for Php Session ID, this ID is only set when a session is running (session is a specially marked browser setting that works like a cookie) you are trying to access a Session ID without having a session running

Answer (score 0):

This code is correct, the issue is the cookie value is null because the session was not set, the user should first go to a PHP page that has session start which sets the cookie value initiate the session

```
<?php 
session_start();
```

Also add a code to check if this cookie is_null.

Comment: cookie is different  by `session`

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean but the OP mentioned cookie with name PHPSESSID which is set by PHP session

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
<?php
session_start();
$cookie = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
file_put_contents("cookie.txt", $cookie, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: the main issue you had was session_start(); . file_put _contents and fwrite should work. the other issue you should note is session_start will set the cookie but $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] will still be empty until the user refresh again so the browser sends the cookie. ideally session_start should be in another page prior to this page where you save the session

Comment: file_put_contents seems to be more efficient, less variables, less lines, more intuitive (at least in my opinion) Am I wrong in that? Which is a better practice?

Comment: file_put_contents for this specific scenario is more efficient you are right, and less code, but I'm only saying it was not the issue.

Comment: I get the cookie for the landing php (where the code is executed) but not from the redirected page. Is there an easy fix ?

Comment: are both pages in the same domain? same directory ? or different paths/domains

Comment: Two different domains. I'm testing out security penetration methods on one of my controlled servers. Printed in a comment box is a link on site A, which will lead them to site B which will steal the session cookie for site A.

Comment: That's a different question. No they can't browser won't allow domains to share sessions(cookies) unless your code explicitly allow it, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328225/sharing-php-session-session-across-multiple-domain

Don't forget to select the best answer for your questions so people coming from google sees selected answers first.