# Define session from domain to another

Tags: php, ajax

I've two websites with two different domains name and I need define a session on my second website using my first one.

Here is my code.

**domain1.com**

```
$.post('https://domain2.com/setter.php', { 'fieldname' : '5Unask819xK', 'value' : '14bx704KnPq6'});
```

**domain2.com**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION[$_POST['fieldname']] = $_POST['value'];
```

And now, at **domain2.com**, if I try run this code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['5Unask819xK'])) {
    echo 'exists';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

I'll get "fail" as response. What am I doing wrong? There are no errors. Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328225/sharing-php-session-session-across-multiple-domain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing php Session ($\_SESSION) across multiple domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328225/sharing-php-session-session-across-multiple-domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set cookies for your domain (and other sites on your domain, like subdomains, if I remember correctly).

This is (mainly ?) for security reasons : else, anyone could set cookies for any website... I let you imagine the mess

(The only way to set cookies for another domain seem to be by exploiting a browser's security hole - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_cooking for instance ; so, in normal cases, not possible -- happily)

Comment: But **domain2.com** will get data from **domain1.com** and create the session. I'm not inserting, just getting.

Comment: As you say you get everytime "fail" cause your condition didn't match any session you have to do that with cokkie or send parameter from your first domain to second domain and get the data from url